# How to call template with name as a variable in XSLT?

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML document which needs to be parsed with an XSLT to HTML.

```
<root>
    <c>
    <c1>
     <id>1</id>
     <text>US</text>
    </c1>
    <c1>
     <id>2</id>
     <text>UK</text>
    </c1>
    </c>
</root>
```

The XSLT for converting this to HTML is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>        
                <xsl:for-each select="c/c1">     
                                **<xsl:variable name="vTemplate" select="text"/>                                  
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vTemplate[@name='text'"/>**
                </xsl:for-each>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xsl:template[@name='text']" name="text">
        <select>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to call a template depends up on the text field. So for the value **US**, one template will be executed and for **UK**, another will executed. 
How to achieve this with a variable as a template name while calling the template? I just made a try but it gives error. Can someone help me to figure out where i made wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to choose name of template to be called dynamically. What could be done is `xsl:choose` utilization (perhaps with combination with `mode` attribute), like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <html>
            <xsl:for-each select="c/c1">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="text = 'US'">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="text" mode="US"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="text = 'UK'">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="text" mode="UK"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:comment>Something's wrong</xsl:comment>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text" mode="US">
        <xsl:comment>US mode</xsl:comment>
        <select>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text" mode="UK">
        <xsl:comment>UK mode</xsl:comment>
        <select>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or you can use `match` with appropriate predicate and avoid `for-each` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//c1" />
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c1[text = 'US']">
        <xsl:comment>US mode</xsl:comment>
        <select id="{id}" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c1[text = 'UK']">
        <xsl:comment>UK mode</xsl:comment>
        <select id="{id}" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `id` attribute of `select` can be also filled by "[Attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)" (xpath in curly brackets) as shown in previous sample.

Comment: This answer is correct on the main question (no, variable references are not allowed in the name attribute of call-template), but less correct on the side issue with which it begins.  There is no reason not to use the same template as both a named template and a match template; sometimes it's quite helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this comment! Although I know it is valid to have one template as both named template and match template I haven't met it in practice yet. Could you please mention (even briefly) such situation? I really appreciate your comment, it would just satisfy my curiosity.